# Count function returns empty record set need it to return 0 instead

Tags: sql-server

I have this query...

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS dupes
FROM documents d JOIN mv_compgift g ON g.documentId = d.id
   JOIN mv_donorid di ON di.documentId = d.id
   JOIN mv_appealcode ac ON ac.documentId = d.id
GROUP BY di.value,ac.value,d.dateDeleted
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
AND g.value = 'Y' 
AND d.dateDeleted IS NULL 
AND di.value = '0621839010'
AND ac.value = 'AD62Q'
```

I need it to show a 0 when I have an empty record-set.

I have looked and tried different functions like coalesce but nothing works...please help.  thanks

Comment: It can't show 0 when the dataset is empty. There are no rows to count. ISNULL or COALESCE isn't going to help either because you have no rows.

Comment: Please copy and paste the code into the question instead, indented by 4 characters (mark the code and hit Ctrl+K or Cmd+K to indent it).

Comment: You're returning count per group, but nothing else from the group, what do you want this query to do exactly?

Comment: It is finding dupes and returns any rows in the table. But if there are not any dupes it returns nothing but I need it to return something.  My application errors when nothing is returned, it checks for rows greater than 1.  it needs to return a number.

Comment: I am not sure how else to explain this. When there are no rows it logically CANNOT return 0 because there are no rows. Why don't you check for the existence of rows in your dot net code? if(MyRecordSet.Rows.Count == 0)...

Comment: You have `having count(*) > 1` so there's no way to have any groups with zero. You also should move the other conditions into a `where` clause.

Comment: ok. thank you all for your help! :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @Count INT

SELECT @Count=COUNT(*) AS dupes
FROM documents d JOIN mv_compgift g ON g.documentId = d.id
   JOIN mv_donorid di ON di.documentId = d.id
   JOIN mv_appealcode ac ON ac.documentId = d.id
GROUP BY di.value,ac.value,d.dateDeleted
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
AND g.value = 'Y' 
AND d.dateDeleted IS NULL 
AND di.value = '0621839010'
AND ac.value = 'AD62Q'

SELECT ISNULL(@Count,0) AS [dupes]
```

Comment: This works well if it is a procedure. I wouldn't declare a bigint though if using count. The count function returns an int, if it is a larger number you would need to use COUNT_BIG.

Comment: I did not know that. Never hit anything nearly that large as far as counting records go.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*), -- raw value
    CASE COUNT(*)
        WHEN 1 THEN 'OK' WHEN 0 THEN 'NOTHING' ELSE 'DUPS'
    END as HasDups -- translated value
FROM documents d JOIN mv_compgift g ON g.documentId = d.id
   JOIN mv_donorid di ON di.documentId = d.id
   JOIN mv_appealcode ac ON ac.documentId = d.id
WHERE g.value = 'Y' AND d.dateDeleted IS NULL 
    AND di.value = '0621839010' AND ac.value = 'AD62Q'
```

Your `HAVING` condition was eliminating groups that didn't have dups. There was no way to ever get a zero back.

Also I'm surprised there wasn't an error on the `g.value` filter. All those conditions appear to belong in `WHERE` rather than `HAVING` anyway.

Comment: This still has the potential to not return any rows.

Comment: @Sean How so? `Count()` will always return a zero when there are no rows. Notice I've removed the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Ahhh didn't notice you removed the group by...nevermind...nothing to see here.